Concerned about the proof of the Model Existence Lemma not using the $(\exists \text{I})$ rule anywhere
TLDR: where in the below proof of the Model Existence Lemma do I need to use the $\exists$ introduction $(\exists \text{I})$ rule?

Trying to fully write the proof of the Model Existence Lemma using Natural Deduction and assuming the only primitives are $=,\neg,\lor,\exists$, I notice that at no point I'm using the $(\exists \text{I})$ rule. I'm thus worried the proof is wrong as an easy application gives the completeness theorem, for which our 'syntactic consequence system' must be strong enough, and I think $(\exists \text{I})$ is needed for that. $\def\bS{\textbf{S}} \def\bT{\textbf{T}} \def\LLL{\mathcal{L}} \def\tE{\text{E}} \def\NN{\mathbb{N}} \def\f{\varphi} \def\y{\psi} \def\MMM{\mathcal{M}} \def\m{\mu} \def\DDD{\mathcal{D}}$

Theorem: let $\bS$ be a (syntactically) consistent set of sentences in the language $\LLL$. Then $\bS$ has a model.
We need a preliminary definition:
Definition: for any set of sentences $\bS$ in the language $\LLL$, define
$$w(\bS) := \bS\cup\bigg\{\phi[c/x] : (\exists x\phi)\in \bS\bigg\}$$
in the language $w(\LLL)$ consisting of $\LLL$ with enough constants $c$ added (one such constant $c$ per $\exists x\phi$ statement in $\bS$ is sufficient). Abbreviate $w(w(\bS))$ as $w^2(\bS)$ and so on.
As the proof is rather long, I will only include the steps and will explain in detail the parts which I believe to be relevant (usually, when existence comes into play).
Proof (sketch):
Step 1: $\bS$ can be extended to a complete, consistent set of sentences $\bS_1$. [...]
Step 2: $\bS_1$ can be extended to a consistent, witnessing set of sentences $\bT_1$ in the new language $\LLL_1\supseteq\LLL$. Simply let
$$\LLL_1 := \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}w^n(\LLL)
\ \ \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \ \ 
\bT_1 := \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}w^n(\bS_1).$$

$\bT_1$ is witnessing: if $(\exists x\phi)$ is in $\bT_1$, then it is in $w^n(\bS_1)$ for some $n$. Thus $\phi[c/x]$ is in $w^{n+1}(\bS_1) \subseteq \bT_1$.
Consistency: we first prove by contradiction that $w$ preserves consistency i.e. if $\bS$ is consistent, so is $w(\bS_1)$. So suppose $w(\bS_1)$ is inconsistent, so that
$$\bS_1,\psi_1[t_1/ x_1],\ldots,\psi_m[t_m/ x_m]\vdash \bot$$
for sentences $\psi_j[t_j/x_j]$ for which $(\exists x_j \psi_j(x_j))\in S$. Adding an extra step to the proof of $\bot$ if necessary (recall that everything follows from $\bot$) we assume that $\bot$ is a sentence in $\LLL$. The goal is to construct a proof of $\bot$ in $\bS_1$. We use $(\exists \tE)$:

$$\frac{
\begin{matrix}
 & & \left[\psi_1[t_1/x_1]\right]\\
 & & \vdots\\
\exists x_1\psi_1(x_1) & & \bot
\end{matrix}}
{\bot}(\exists \tE)$$
providing us with $\bS_1,\psi_2[t_2/x_2],\ldots,\psi_m[t_m/x_m]\vdash \bot$. Applying the argument $m$ times gives $\bS_1\vdash \bot$, which is a contradiction. Now $w^n(\bS)$ is consistent for all $n$ by induction. Finally we show, again by contradiction, that $\bT_1$ is consistent. If not, there are $\f_1,\ldots,\f_r$ all in $\bT_1$ such that $\{\f_1,\ldots,\f_r\}\vdash \bot$. As there is some $w^n(\bS)$ containing all these $\f_i$, this $w^n(\bS)$ is also inconsistent, a contradiction.
Step 3: now $\bT_1$ may not be complete, so we extend it into a complete theory $\bS_2$. As $\bS_2$ may lack witnesses, we add witnesses to form $\bT_2$ in the new language $\LLL_2$. Repeating this process ad infinum, and letting
$$\overline{\bS} := \bigcup_{n\in\NN} \bS_n,
\ \ \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \ \ 
\overline{\LLL} := \bigcup_{n\in\NN}\LLL_n$$
we will have at last complete, consistent, and witnessing extension $\overline{\bS}$ of $\bS$. [...]
Step 4: define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on closed terms of $\overline{\LLL}$ by $s\sim t$ iff $\overline{\bS}\vdash (s = t)$. We show $\sim$ is indeed an equivalence relation [...]
Step 5: we now define our model $\MMM$ as having domain $\DDD := \overline{\LLL}_T$ and $\mu$ being defined by

Any constant $c$ is sent to $[c]$.
Any $n$-place predicate $P$ is mapped to the predicate $P^\MMM\in\DDD_R$ defined by
$$P^\MMM([t_1], \ldots,[t_n]) \iff \overline{\bS} \vdash P(t_1,\ldots,t_n).$$
Any $n$-place function $f$ is mapped to the function $f^\MMM$ defined by
$$f^\MMM : ([t_1],\ldots,[t_n])\mapsto [f(t_1,\ldots,t_n)].$$
We show these are well-defined [...]

Step 6:  for each sentence $\f\in\overline{\LLL}_S$, we show $\overline{\bS}\vdash \f$ implies $\f^\MMM$.

Atomic sentences:

Of the form $(s = t)$: [...]
Of the form $\f(t_1,\ldots,t_n)$: [...]


Induction step:

Of the form $(\neg \f)$: [...]
Of the form $(\f \lor \y)$: [...]
Of the form $\exists x\f(x)$:
\begin{alignat*}{2}
&\overline{\bS}\vdash \exists x\f(x)\\
\text{if and only if } & \left(\overline{\bS}\vdash \f(c)\right) && \text{ by witnessing of $\overline{\bS}$.}\\
\text{if and only if } & \f(c)^\MMM && \text{ by the inductive hypothesis.}\\
\text{implies } & \left(\exists x\f(x)\right)^\MMM && \text{ by definition of $(\exists x\f(x))^\MMM$.}\\
\end{alignat*}



Now, as $\overline{\bS}\vdash \f$ for every $\f\in\overline{\bS}$, we must have that $\MMM$ is a model of $\overline{\bS}$, and thus a model of $\overline{\bS}$.

Step 6: you have written it as: $\overline{S}\vdash \varphi \text { implies } \varphi^{\mathcal M}$ [i.e. formula $\varphi$ holds in structure $\mathcal M$].
This sounds correct, because the expected result, i.e. the Model Existence Theorem is:

if $\Gamma$ is consistent, then $\Gamma$ has a model.

But to run the proof what you need is:

For every sentence $\varphi$ such that... $\ \overline {S}\vdash \varphi \text { IFF } \varphi^{\mathcal M}$.

Why so? In the final case, that for: $\exists x \varphi$, we use the witnessing property to have $\overline{S}\vdash \varphi[x←c]$.
But then you apply the Induction Hypotheses with IFF to get $(\varphi [x←c])^{\mathcal M}$, and thus the claim must be expressed with IFF.
In order to license the IFF with the Existential-case we must have: Let $(∃x)\varphi$ holds in $\mathcal M$; then $\varphi[x←c]$ holds by witnessing and thus $\overline S \vdash \varphi [x←c]$ from which $∃x \varphi$ by $(\exists \text I)$.
Added for the comment
Why we cannot break the chain of IFFs?
Consider the negation clause: $\lnot \varphi$: we assume $\overline S \vdash \lnot \varphi$, and thus, by consistency: $\overline S \nvdash \varphi$, and applying I.H. $\varphi$ does not hold in $\mathcal M$.
But going from $\overline S \nvdash \varphi$ to $\mathcal M \nvDash \varphi$ is: if $\varphi^{\mathcal M}$, then $\overline S \vdash \varphi$.

There is just one thing I'm still confused about: what if we use the inductive hypothesis with an implies? It seems to me we will still be able to deduce $\varphi(c)^\mathcal{M}$.

Hello! Sorry to be a bother, but you have not answered to my comment (:

@Sam the answer has been atted to the main answer.
